# ¿Cómo identificar la posición de un valor en un array sin necesidad de recorrer todos los elementos?

Tags: javascript

pues tal y como pone en el titulo no se como hacer para que marque la posición del un valor del array sin recorrer todos los elementos en este caso quiero sacar el valor 5, aquí mi código que llevo hasta ahora:

```
function numeros(){
var numeros1 = [4,0,3,4,8,5,3,1,4,8,4,3,2,6,1,8,9,7,8,5,0,1,5];
let greaterTen2 = numeros1.filter(number => number = 5 );

alert(greaterTen2)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el indice usa el **indexOf()**, por ejemplo

```js
function numeros(){
var numeros1 = [4,0,3,4,8,5,3,1,4,8,4,3,2,6,1,8,9,7,8,5,0,1,5];
let greaterTen2 = numeros1.indexOf(5);

alert(greaterTen2)
}

numeros();
```

Ten en cuenta que el índice de los array son en base 0, por lo que la primera posición seria el 0 la sexta será la posición 5...

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió